# Nomenclature priorities with ethers, acyl groups and ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

$\hspace{6cm}$[image: first]

**(2-oxopropionyl)oxy butanoic acid**

$\hspace{6.5cm}$[image: second]

**3,4-dioxo 4-methoxy butanoic acid**

$\hspace{6.3cm}$[image: third]

**3-(2-oxopropyl),6-oxo heptanoic acid**

$\hspace{6.25cm}$[image: fourth]

**3-propionyl,6-oxo heptanoic acid**

$\hspace{6.3cm}$[image: fifth]

**3-(3-oxobutyl),6-oxo hexanoic acid**

Aldehyde takes priority over ketone, yes?

Have I got these right?

PS: With the third molecule, wouldn't it be convenient if we could have a ketonyl group so that instead of **2-oxopropyl** , one could say **propanonyl**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle, your assumptions about the order of priority for classes is correct. According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, the order of seniority of classes in decreasing order of seniority is as follows.

> (…)
>   7. acids
>   (…)
>   9. esters
>   (…)
>   15. aldehydes
>   16. ketones
>   (…)
>   42. ethers
>   (…)

Thus, it is correct that the names for all compounds given in the question have the suffix ‘oic acid’.

However, the names proposed by you still contain a few errors.

Your name “(2-oxopropionyl)oxy butanoic acid” is ambiguous since the locant for the complex substituent group ‘(2-oxopropionyl)oxy’ is missing.
The complete name is “4-[(2-oxopropionyl)oxy]butanoic acid”.
However, the preferred name is **4-[(2-oxopropanoyl)oxy]butanoic acid**.

Your other names include the correct suffixes and locants; however, the suffixes are not cited in alphabetical order. The correct names are

- **4-methoxy-3,4-dioxobutanoic acid** (not “3,4-dioxo 4-methoxy butanoic acid”)
- **6-oxo-3-(2-oxopropyl)heptanoic acid** (not “3-(2-oxopropyl),6-oxo heptanoic acid”)
- **6-oxo-3-propanoylheptanoic acid** (not “3-propionyl,6-oxo heptanoic acid”)
- **6-oxo-3-(3-oxopropyl)heptanoic acid** (not “3-(3-oxobutyl),6-oxo hexanoic acid”)

Comment: Sorry, I drew the first one wrong. Edited now.  Anyway, the the whole point I drew that one was I wanted to know, whenever there is an oxygen atom double bonded to the end carbon of a substituent group, does it automatically become an acyl?