IUPAC nomenclature of carboxylic acid halides
In IUPAC nomenclature of acid halides, the prefixes used for them is haloformyl and halocarbonyl. Does anyone know the difference between these two, or can they be used interchangeably?
I searched everywhere, somewhere it even said that the prefix used for acid halides is halocarbonyl only.

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117065/difference-between-oxo-and-formyl ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/76360/17368

HaloCarbonyl is correct and is the most commonly used prefix. I think Haloformyl might be the more official IUPAC name. They probably can be used interchangeably but HaloCarbonyl is more common

@user155568 What you said sounds reasonable..But are you sure that they can be used interchangeably or it's just a guess..?

Google and clearly people definitely prefer HaloCarbonyl however IUPAC uses Haloformyl. Context would be good but in general, most people use HaloCarbonyl

Don't use capital letters for emphasis.

@user155568 Then, Can we say that HaloCarbonyl is a common name ? Since, you're saying that it's not used by IUPAC

Halocarbonyl is generally a more common term yes
